# trying to figure out how to fill array in php

Tags: php, zend-gdata

guys not native english speaker, so im trying my best to explain my question here

```
    foreach($columnFeed as $cellEntry){
    $result[$cellEntry->cell->getColumn()] = $cellEntry->cell->getText();
}
```

that piece of code fills me an array with rows and values row => value,,,
now using zend g data, if a cell is empty it simply wont return anything, like in row 112 col 4, if its empty, nothing will be displayed, i need to assign a value to that key value in particular IF its empty , in a for loop or a foreach maybe,

i can do it like this right now

```
if(!isset($result[14]))
{
    $result[14] = "0:00";
    echo $result[14];
}
```

it outputs position 14 of $result as 0:00 correctly,
but as you can see it is not the best way since i will be having columns from #1 to #14 , and some cases more, i would end up having tons of if statements,,,

i tried doing it this way

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) 
{
    if(!isset($result[$key]))
    {
        $result[$value] = "0:00";
    }
}
```

i know somethings wrong, but cant figure out what is,  coud someone please point me in the right direction maybe with the correct term of what i need to search or something like that.

after all that the `$result[$value here]` will be used in some array like this

```
    $data = array (
    'in' => $result[number of index],
    'out' => $result[number of index]
);
```

to fill up a google spreadsheet using zend gdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With isset() you are checking for !isset($result[$key]) with $key and assigning with variable $value as index to $result[$value] = "0:00"; hence value not setting properly.
Please make following changes in our code If you want value in $key to be set as index of $result.

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) 
{
    if(!isset($result[$key]))
    {
        $result[$key] = "0:00";
    }
}
```